# how do I get the parent node of an entity reference node

Tags: nodes

I have two content types - A and B.  For content type A, there are 5 content items - Aa, Ab, Ac, Ad, Ae.  For content type B, I have two items Ba, Bb.  Content type B has a field that is an entity reference of  content type A.  In a single page I have the following setup:

Ba -> Aa, Ab, Ac, Ad, Ae
Bb -> Aa, Ab, Ac, Ad, Ae

I have a twig template for B and a separate one for A.  When rendering Aa - Ae, I need to know if the container node is Ba or Bb because it is rendered differently.  Ba and Bb know about the referenced entities (Aa - Ae), but the referenced entities don't know who their parent is.

I've tried using the preprocessor but I can't seem to find a way to get the parent (containter) node.

Any suggestions?

TIA.

Comment: These types of relations are often done with Views, you can create a Block for example that is showing either the children of the current node or the parents of the current node. I think the most common way of labeling these connections is that your Bs would be children and As would be parents.

Comment: Following that last logic would mean creating 10 nodes of type A rather than just the 5 used twice, right?

Comment: No, I guess I didn't express myself clear enough. I was just commenting on which "sides" to call a child or a parent, as commonly used in articles. There are many tutorials about relations through ER fields so I wanted to warn about the perspective if you decide to investigate further in that direction :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this:

```
$loaded_nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties([
  'field_node_reference' => $node->id(),
]);
$parent_node = reset($loaded_nodes);
```

Replace the field name with your actual field name.

Comment: How to render parent node field values on the template file.

Comment: You would need to implement the above in a preproccess function for the template.